# Paypal Express checkout sandbox not working

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am getting empty array when call paypal setExpresschecout function with sandbox credential. 
if i put live credential then its work fine. 
This problem occur from last couple of week. before that the code worked fine on both live and sandbox credential.
Anyone have any idea?? Please Help.

Comment: please provide an example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Did you check which version of SSL/TLS your are using to make the API call?

PayPal recently upgraded to TLS 1.2 as you can see on their developer blog:
https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/#tls

For now it's only on the sandbox but they are going to do this on the live environment in the future.

It means if you're using TLS 1.1 or 1.0 for your API call it won't work anymore.

I had to update my test server because it was impossible to call their API anymore.

Comment: Thanks you Tom. Sandbox credential work on my ssl certified site.

Comment: A certificate would not change anything. You need check which version of SSL you are using to make the API calls. If your'e using a deprecated one PayPal will block the API call. If you use CURL to make the call it should use the most recent version installed on your web server. Then likely you have to update your server.